# Developing a PHP/mySQL app on IIs

Tags: php, mysql, windows, iis

I am strictly a LAMP dev but an ad agency I work with is courting a government agency whose RFP requires that their site be delivered via a Windows server.

What advice do folks have on this?  Are there specific pitfalls?  It seems like I have heard that file uploads and folder permissions are very different on Windows servers.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IME, IIS [can behave **very** oddly](http://symcbean.blogspot.com/2009/02/more-iis-oddities.html) at times.

The permissions model is primarily ACL based - so its certainly possible to design a system which mimics the way Unix works - but (just as with Unix) get the permissions model right - and don't tinker with permissions / ownership in your code.

And of course you'll get yourself tied in knots if you try to move up directory hierarchies and cross over 'drives'.

Add to that a complete absence of the services you might invoke via popen(), and the POSIX tools.

Yes, people keep telling me its a nice place to visit but I wouldn't want to live there.

OTOH, a self-contained set of PHP files will run quite happily there.

Answer (score 1):

PHP on a windows server is definitely trying on your patience. Problems that I've run into are making sure that IIS is configured to use the correct php.ini file, and as you said, writing to files on the server as well as folder permissions.

That being said, if you can get it working correctly, it's not a bad production environment.

I would suggest getting your dev environment as similar as possible to what production will look like. That way you run into as few problems as possible when you deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I can see some pitfalls for using PHP on IIS

1. Since IIS is multithreaded unlike
   linux which is multiprocess. Some
   PHP scripts might be unsafe.
2. Because of this PHP should be installed and
   run as a CGI extension. CGI is
   slower than IIS's ISAPI and worse
   when compared to Apache's mod_php.
3. Another pitfall I can think of is URL rewriting. IIS, versions below
   v7 do not support url rewriting.
4. Configuration of PHP with IIS is really a pain. But when you do configure it, make sure you use the same configuration, exact mirror images everywhere you are developing because a lot can go wrong with just one glitch.

Comment: If you got IIS7, then you can run PHP with FastCGI (http://php.iis.net/). It's also a lot easier to manage. And for IIS6, there is no native support for rewriting, but you can use: http://www.isapirewrite.com/

Comment: FastCGI is, in many situations, faster than mod_php anyway.  We use a fastcgi setup w/Linux and Apache for performance reasons - it means we can use the multithreaded worker MPM for apache and that the PHP overhead is only there for PHP requests, not for every image, css and js file as it is with mod_php.

Comment: ? "IIS is multithreaded" - like to explain how you can run PHP in the same process/thread as IIS? There is no mod_php for IIS - the only options are CGI/FastCGI